# Use/advantage of Array Destructing?

Tags: javascript, eslint, destructuring, eslint-config-airbnb

I have recently moved to 'airbnb-base' eslint style-guide. There i am get an error when i try to reference the array elements with index **eslint(prefer-destructuring)**.

eg

```
let a = {};
// get an error saying eslint(prefer-destructuring)
a.b = clients[0];
```

What is wrong with using accessing Array with index or how is using array destructuring better ?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. You just picked a style guide that prefers one notation over the other.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Just wanted to know the intent in preferring destructuring.

Comment: Well, for one, it gets rid of the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what AirBnB has to say about the need for these rules.

**5.1 Use object destructuring when accessing and using multiple properties of an object. eslint: prefer-destructuring**

*Why? Destructuring saves you from creating temporary references for those properties.*

**5.3 Use object destructuring for multiple return values, not array destructuring.**

*Why? You can add new properties over time or change the order of things without breaking call sites.*

The explanation for all the rules can be found in https://github.com/airbnb/javascript